# Can I make text on a path with a shadow more controllable?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, creative-cloud, pen-tool, path-effects

I am wanting to create a 3 dimensional block text effect but also have text on a curved path. So far I have tried creating text on a path then going to Transform Each and duplicating the text multiple times to add dimension which creates the below result.

[image]

The angle isn't quite what I want. I have also made it without the text on a path and the drop shadow angle is more what I'm after.

[image]

Ideally I would like to after I've created the drop shadow on the straight text to then put everything on a curved path. From what I understand however the drop shadow part has to be expanded and made into artwork rather then text. So then the dilemma would be I can't put it on a path because its not text. Unless there is a technique to make artwork follow a path?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with live text and an Envelope Distort.

Make your text, add your block shadow (here I use an Astute Graphics plug in called AG Block Shadow- they have really great plug ins, but they cost $), Select your text, then go to Object> Envelope Distort> Make With Warp.

There are many different base options in the "Make with Warp" dialog with their own adjustments. You can also use the white arrow (Direct Selction Tool) to select and adjust your base paths and anchors and move them as you like. You can also double click into the Envelope and add or alter your text.

[image]

Comment: +1 -- but the issue with envelopes is that they **always** distort text, regardless of their settings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue may be. It could be the use of `Transform Each` on *duplicates*.

- Place the type on a path
- Add an additional Fill to the type, via the **Appearance Panel**
- Move the new fill below  the `Characters` item on the **Appearance Panel**
- Then use `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` on that new fill

The result is essentially the same shadow as you have on the straight text.

[image]

Here the **Effect** is generating duplicates via the `Copies` field, and applying the same transformation to each copy, as opposed to *actually* duplicating any artwork.